# SelectedItem only updates first row in database in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I am developing an application to allow a user to enter their employee details of their company into a database. So far I am experimenting with WPF and trying to implement MVVM within my application while using Entity Framework.

I'm creating a Master-Detail application, and have been researching into how to achieve this using MVVM, as I'm very much new to it all.

One of the ways in which I have tried is by creating a property within my `View-Model` called `SelectedEmployee` and then binding it to a `List View` in my xaml, like so;

```
public Employee _SelectedEmployee;
public Employee SelectedEmployee
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedEmployee;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_SelectedEmployee == value)
            return;

        _SelectedEmployee = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
    }
}
```

```xml
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listview" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
ItemsSource="{Binding LoadEmployee}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Height="150" Grid.Row="1">
```

I then have a method that allows the user to update a `SelectedItem` within the `List View`. But this is where the problem occurs. When I select an item from the `List View`, it only updates the first row from the database and not the row I wanted to select.

Here's the method;

```
    public void UpdateEmployee(Employee emp)
    {
        using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
        {
                emp = context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeID == SelectedEmployee.EmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();

                emp.Title = Title;
                emp.FirstName = FirstName;
                emp.Surname = Surname;
                emp.Position = Position;
                emp.DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth;
                emp.Address = Address;
                emp.Country = Country;
                emp.Postcode = Postcode;
                emp.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
                emp.MobileNumber = MobileNumber;
                emp.FaxNumber = FaxNumber;
                emp.Email = Email;
                emp.NINumber = NINumber;
                emp.ChargableResource = ChargableResource;
                emp.ChargeOutRate = ChargeOutRate;
                emp.TimeSheetRequired = TimeSheetRequired;
                emp.WorkShift = WorkShift;
                emp.BenefitsProvided = BenefitsProvided;

                context.Employees.ApplyCurrentValues(emp);
                context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I have bound my properties within my `view model` to the `text-boxes` within my xaml and then implementing `OnPropertyChanged`. 
I am also using Commands to limit the amount of `code-behind` as its important for testability and maintainability.

Here is the command method to update;

```
    private ICommand showUpdateCommand;
    public ICommand ShowUpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (showUpdateCommand == null)
            {
                showUpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(this.UpdateFormExecute, this.UpdateFormCanExecute);
            }
            return showUpdateCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool UpdateFormCanExecute()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) ...
     }

    private void UpdateFormExecute()
    {
        UpdateOrganisationTypeDetail();
    }
```

As I am new to MVVM, I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong so would appreciate some input please :).

Comment: Thinking about your problem, but i will go ahead and point out "emp.WorkShift = BenefitsProvided;" is probably a typo.

Comment: @Nathan Cooper Yes certainly was a typo, got too excited. Sorry. It has been amended. But same problem still applies.

Comment: If you debug it: What is the SelectedEmployee.EmployeeID in the following row(?): emp = context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeID == SelectedEmployee.EmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @Björn thanks for your reply. It is 24 (which is the first row in the database). No matter which row I select from the `List View` it just automatically updates the row first within the database.

Comment: Can we assume the first bit of your code works, what happens if you bind it into a datagrid <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>    datagrid1/datacontext = whateveryourobservablecollectionofemployeesiscalled
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid> datagrid1.datacontext = yourobservablecollectionofstaff

Comment: @NathanCooper Thanks for your reply. It does work but not the way that I would like it too, as it is not fully functional. I have also tried with a `Data grid` which produced the same output, so thought I'd try something different and use a `List View` to see if there was any difference, and turned out not to be the case.

Comment: What is the binding LoadEmployee? Is it a property in your view model? Is the UpdateEmployee method in the ViewModel? Could you give us some more code please :-)

Comment: @Björn Yes, the UpdateEmployee and LoadEmployee are both in the `EmployeeViewModel`. The LoadEmployee is as follows;              public List<Employee> LoadEmployee
{
   get
   {
      using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
   {
      var query = from e in context.Employees
                  select e;
      return query.ToList<Employee>();
    }
    }
}

Comment: OK. How is the view model created for the view and how is the UpdateEmplyee method called from the view?

Comment: @Björn No I haven' been able to solve it unfortunately :/. The view is created like so; <Window.DataContext><vm:OrganisationViewModel/</Window.DataContext>

Comment: @gregory.bmclub And you are using a command to trigger the Update? Very strange... Could you post more of your code so I can follow the entire "chain", from loading to selecting to saving?

Comment: @Björn I added the update command in the question. Cheers

Comment: @gregory.bmclub I'm sorry but I can't help you just by the provided excerpts. But your main problem is that SelectedEmployee.EmployeeID always is 24 (which is the first row in the list). My guess would be that you are getting two different datacontexts (view models) somehow. Also, since the LoadEmployee always returns a new collection, it might cause problems. Do you have to do it like that or could you get it just once and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then perhaps the problem is with your updating. I don't really understand what your trying to do with listview, but since it's not working in a simple datagrid this might help. it's not so much an answer as something that I wrote to find your error that happens not to contain your error. please do comment if anything is awry.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static MainViewModel _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    public static ObservableCollection<Employee> staff = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = _mainViewModel;
        dataGrid1.DataContext = staff;
        listview.DataContext = staff;

        Employee Employee1 = new Employee();
        Employee1.name = "Jeff";
        staff.Add(Employee1);
        Employee Employee2 = new Employee();
        Employee2.name = "Jefferson";
        staff.Add(Employee2);
        Employee2.name = "Tim";

    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _SelectedEmployee;
    public string SelectedEmployee
    {
        get { return _SelectedEmployee; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedEmployee = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hang on listview is giving me crap now.

Comment: The purpose of the `ListView` is to show the represented data from the database - as I tried to use a `datagrid` and the same problem occurred. Also, with your proposed answer I am trying to implement MVVM, and therefore having code-behind defeats the whole purpose, from what I have learn't. Nether-the-less, I will give it a go and let you know, cheers :).